# SQL delete MIN plus the next greatest in a group

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

```
What I get                  What I need

id  hash    assigned        id  hash    assigned
--  ----    --------        --  ----    --------
1   1j      1               1   1j      1
2   1j-1    1               3   1j-2    1
3   1j-2    1               4   3m      1
4   3m      1               6   3m-8    1
5   3m-3    1               7   f7      1
6   3m-8    1               8   6q      0
7   f7      1               9   3y      0
8   6q      0               10  3y-3    0
9   3y      0               
10  3y-3    0
```

My data set looks similar to this.  The hash is always a certain number long, in this case 2 characters.  It is modified after sync with an extension that is sequential but not by the same number of units.  I need to delete the first modification of those assigned 1.

This is my non working best guess:

```
DELETE 
  FROM `table` 
  WHERE (`assigned`=1) 
    IN (SELECT `hash`, min(`hash`)+1 FROM `table` GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`hash`,1 , 2) ORDER BY hash ASC;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have problems with string comparisons once your counter gets into double and triple digits. This is a straightforward approach that should probably get you close. Remember to try is out as a `select` before you actually delete everything.

```
delete from T
where
    assigned = 1
    -- Business requirement not explained.
    -- I'm assuming the entire group has the same assigned value.

    and hash = (
        select min(hash) from T as t2
            where 
                    left(t2.hash, 2) = left(T.hash, 2)
                and t2.hash > (
                    select min(hash) from T as t3
                    where left(t3.hash, 2) = left(t2.hash, 2)
                )
    )
```

Comment: This works great in SELECT but with DELETE in MySQL I get error #1093 -   So, I modified it thus: DELETE FROM `T`
WHERE
    `assigned` = 1

    AND `hash` = (
        SELECT MIN(`hash`) FROM (SELECT * FROM T) as t2
            WHERE 
                    LEFT(`t2`.`hash`, 2) = LEFT(`T`.`hash`, 2)
                AND `t2`.`hash` > (
                    SELECT min(`hash`) FROM (SELECT * FROM `T`) as `t3`
                    WHERE LEFT(`t3`.`hash`, 2) = LEFT(`t2`.`hash`, 2)
                )
    )  .  This works.  Thanks.  I learned a lot.

Comment: Interesting. I don't really use MySQL a lot and I worried it wouldn't like something. Glad you found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server

```
delete from T where id in (
    select 
       t1.id
    from T t1
    where t1.assigned = 1 and t1.hash like '%-%' and not exists (
      select * from T t2 where left(t1.hash, 2) = left(t2.hash, 2) and t2.hash like '%-%' and
            cast(substring(t2.hash, 4, len(t2.hash) - 3) as int) <
            cast(substring(t1.hash, 4, len(t1.hash) - 3) as int)
    )
)
```